# How Best to handle oData, JSON data with Google Maps API

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, odata

I'm sorry for such a basic question but this is all very new to me. What would be the best way to handle this scenario:

1. Access address data via oData
2. Can only obtain 50 records at a time via oData
3. Allow user to select what gets retrieved using some kind of toggle switch based on a status field (some selections will result in more than 50 records)
4. Toggle visibility of markers based on checkboxes

How do I combine the various oData calls during the selection process?  How do i toggle markers based on status data stored in JSON?  Or do i have it all wrong?  Thank you for any help you guys can provide to get me going in the right direction.